# The slide show is not working in LibreOffice 

Tags: 11.10, libreoffice

When I create a presentation in LibreOffice and click the button for slide show, nothing happens, the screen gets sort of freezed, its frustating.

Besides, image viewer also works no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually problem was a bit complex. I had installed certain packages using freshubuntu (something similar)repository. Later on i purged that repository. Because of this my certain packages got somewhat locked, i.e. couldn't update which created such issues. 
Solution:
open synaptic
look for obsolete packages.
find the packages for those packages from launchpad
replace them.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening, is that Libreoffice has opened another, fullscreen window for the presentation. To get out of it, hit escape. As for getting the slides to display properly, I have no idea. I was trying to do a presentation tonight and this tripped me up. I can't comment or upvote yet, so please Someone help us out.